# Find transformation between two sets of points by minimizing the maximum distance

Tags: geometry, optimization

There are two sets of four 2D points.
There is a 1 to 1 correspondence between the two sets.
The points in both sets are close to the following nominal positions, only deviate with a random value in both direction: (-1.5, 0.0), (-0.5, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0), (-1.5, 0.0).

I would like to find a transformation (translation and rotation), which brings one set over the other by minimizing the maximum distance between the corresponding points:

$f = max(||a_i - b_i||^2 : i = 1, 2, 3, 4)$

I tried different optimization methods in the Python Scipy.optimisation package, but non of them worked well. They are close, but not perfect. I am not intereseted in any other best fit algorithms (SVD, PCA etc.).
Playing with random datasets, I observed, that in some cases after the optimization, two pairs of points have the same distance, sometime three.

Is there any algorithm, geometrical approach to find the global minimum of f?

Here is an example, before any optimization. Let's say, we want to move the orange points over the blue ones by minimizing `f`. The circles help to judge the current distances.

[image]

**Update 8/3/2024:**

I double checked my results with Matlab and got similar results.
I used the same data set as above:

```
A= [-2.21405945, -0.0735467;
    -1.08033674, -0.05451294;
     0.98732845,  0.11462708;
     2.22058245,  0.08284019];

B = [-2.58064647, -0.2670957;
     -0.4799502 , -0.06829777;
      0.69444341,  0.17659052;
      2.4039824 , -0.11898507];
```

Using `fminsearch` with increased tolerances (`options = optimset('TolX',1e-16, 'TolFun', 1e-16, 'MaxFunEvals', 10000);`) I got the following distances (B moved over A):

```
   0.488352744907114
   0.488352744907114
   0.395541348617930
   0.329367461145935
```

Graphically:
[image]
It is visible, that the left two point pairs are not in one line. If all four points would be on one line, and the center of gravity of the 2 orange and the center of gravity of the 2 blue points are at the same location, the distances will be the minimum.

```
   0.488099690097153
   0.488099690097153
   0.389873728301958
   0.407380216427823
```

Graphically:
[image]

The two point pairs are closer than before, the 3rd one also, but in case of the 4th one the distance increased, but still smaller than the maximum (1st/2nd point), which was the goal.

I think, one can come up with similar simple rules two find the true optimum.

Comment: I can't find a geometrical approach, but the usual analytical way should be tolerably simple: you have a well defined function of three parameters (a vector for the translation and an angle for the rotation) and algorithms to find its minimum should work quite well. I tried for instance with Mathematica and got a result which should be the minimum.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca: I double checked my results with Matlab and got similar results like with scipy. I updated my question with the results.

Comment: Are the points in the same sequence in each set?

Comment: @Cesareo: Yes, they are.

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`. You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ using `\max`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is to find the three parameters $\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta$ (translation to $x$, translation to $y$, angle of rotation).  Define a loss function $\Phi(\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta)$ that measures the "badness" of using a particular set of parameter values.  Specifically, it is given by

$$\Phi(\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^4 \|T_{\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta}(a_i)-b_i\|^2,$$

where $T_{\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta}$ denotes translation and rotation as given by the parameters, and $a_i,b_i$ are the two sets of four points.  Thus $\Phi$ represents the total error after transforming then.

Now use any standard algorithm to find $\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta$ that minimize $\Phi(\delta_x,\delta_y,\theta)$.  This is a numerical optimization problem and you can try any standard optimization method: [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent), [Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method), [particle swarm optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization), etc.

Your problem comes up in [image registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_registration), also known as image alignment.  See especially [point-set registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-set_registration), which is basically your problem.  There are many standard algorithms, and you may be able to apply existing methods.  In that setting, people are concerned about outliers, and want to ignore a few outlier points.  Since it seems you don't have to deal with outliers, you can use simpler methods.

Answer (score 1):

As the points are ordered, a rigid motion can be implemented using a translation and a rotation. Given the sets $A$ and $B$, the distances can be computed as

$$
d_i^{\gamma} =\|a_i - R(\theta)\cdot(b_i-p_0)+p_0\|^{\gamma}
$$

with $R(\theta)$ a rotation matrix and $p_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ and $\gamma = \{0,1,2\}$ represents the selected norm. To have a democratic distance we choose the involved optimization procedure as

$$
\min_{\theta,x_0,y_0}\left(\max_i d_i^{\gamma}(\theta,x_0,y_0)\right)
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script implementing this procedure. We can choose between `obj0, obj1, obj2` to perform the optimization. For the task, it is advisable to use a solver that uses evolutionary procedures. In red the set $A$, in blue the set $B$ and in black the adjusted $B$ set.

```
A = {{-2.21405945, -0.0735467},
     {-1.08033674, -0.05451294},
     {0.98732845, 0.11462708},
     {2.22058245, 0.08284019}};

B = {{-2.58064647, -0.2670957},
     {-0.4799502, -0.06829777},
     {0.69444341, 0.17659052},
     {2.4039824, -0.11898507}};

R = RotationMatrix[theta];
n = Length[A];
p0 = {x0, y0};
Btheta = Table[R . (B[[k]] - p0) + p0, {k, 1, Length[A]}];

obj0 = Max[Table[Abs[A[[k]] - Btheta[[k]]], {k, 1, n}]];
obj1 = Max[Table[Total[Abs[A[[k]] - Btheta[[k]]]], {k, 1, n}]];
obj2 = Max[Table[Norm[A[[k]] - Btheta[[k]]], {k, 1, n}]];
obj = obj0;
sol = NMinimize[obj, {x0, y0, theta}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

Btheta0 = Btheta /. sol[[2]];
gr1 = ListPlot[Btheta0, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.02]}];
gr2 = ListPlot[B, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02]}];
gr3 = ListPlot[A, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, AspectRatio -> 1/8, Axes -> False]
```

For $\gamma=0$

[image]

For $\gamma=1$

[image]

For $\gamma = 2$

[image]

Comment: The maximum norm is the $p=\infty$ norm, not the $p=0$ norm.

Comment: You don’t need $p_0$ twice in the transformation. Effectively you’re translating by $R(\theta)p_0+p_0$; since this maps $p_0$ twice, you’d have the same set of transformations with just one of the $p_0$.

Comment: The results for $\gamma=2$ don’t look right. If I understand correctly, the maximum distance from a black dot to its blue partner is being minimized. Then three pairs should have the same distance, because otherwise you can translate such as to reduce the two maximum distances. In this case, the second and fourth pair have the maximum distance, and it can be reduced by translating upwards and leftwards.

Comment: Yes you are right. I put a command in `Matlab` style when programming `MATHEMATICA` . I put for instance `Max[Abs[A - Btheta]]` instead of `Max[Table[Total[Abs[A[[k]] - Btheta[[k]]]], {k, 1, n}]]`. Now it is corrected. Thanks for helping.